# Creating Kiosk application for Windows

Tags: c#, browser, kiosk

I'd like to create Kiosk application for Windows 8 tablet.
 
So is there a common way of creating such applications? 
And is there any difference of creating desctop application for PC and tablet (I mean, will my desctop application which was developed, for example, for windows 7 on PC correctly work under Windows 8 on tablet)?
Back to previous question, if I create full screen application with [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) control inside will it be a good solution?

Comment: That's pretty unusual.  Do prepare for having to buy a new tablet at least once a week, they'll easily walk off without trace.  Ways to mount a tablet so they don't disappear are quite limited.  Not an issue with panel-mount touch displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows 8.1 Assisted Access feature to build Kiosk apps
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Start with http://dev.windows.com/ to find out about Windows 8 apps.

If by tablet you are thinking the Surface (not Pro) then you are looking at WinRT

Store apps will run on Win 8 and RT but not Windows 7. Windows 7/8 Desktop apps will not run on RT.